# Sum of two fields based on some conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

These are my documents in `Stat` collection:

```
{placeid: 'plaza', guestid: "xxx", logtype: "purchase", value: 12}
{placeid: 'plaza', guestid: "xxx", logtype: "visit", value: 0}
{placeid: 'plaza', guestid: "xxx", logtype: "purchase", value: 17}
{placeid: 'plaza', guestid: "yyy", logtype: "visit", value: 0}
```

I want to aggregate these documents to get information (passed `plaza` as argument):

- `xxx` visited: 1, purchases: 2, value of purchases is 29
- `yyy` visited: 1, purchases: 0, value of purchases is 0

This is my approach:

```
Stat.aggregate(
        [
            { $match: { placeid: "plaza" } },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$guestid",
                    totallogs: { $sum: 1 },
                    totalvalue: { $sum: "$value" },
                }
            }
        ]
)
```

problem here is that this aggregation does not take `logtype` into consideration.

And I do not know how to improve it. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the aggregation framework to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) your documents by "guestid" and use the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) accumulator operator to return the sum. Of course you also need the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator evaluates the value of "logtype" and returns the value of the "true case".

```js
db.Stat.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "placeid": "plaza" } },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$guestid", 
        "visit": { 
            "$sum": { 
                "$cond": [ 
                    { "$eq": [ "$logtype", "visit" ] }, 
                    1, 
                    0 
                ] 
            } 
         }, 
         "purchases": { 
             "$sum": { 
                  "$cond": [ 
                      { "$eq": [ "$logtype", "purchase" ] }, 
                      1, 
                      0 
                  ] 
             } 
        }, 
        "value_purchase": { 
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ 
                    { "$eq": [ "$logtype",   "purchase" ] },
                    "$value", 
                    0 
                ]  
            } 
        }  
    }}
])
```

which produces:

```js
{ "_id" : "yyy", "visit" : 1, "purchases" : 0, "value_purchase" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "xxx", "visit" : 1, "purchases" : 2, "value_purchase" : 29 }
```